# Curvature form, tangent bundle and structural group.

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

Let $T\mathbb{C}P^n$ the tangent bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^n$. We have that the Chern classes are the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of curvature form $\Omega$ of $T\mathbb{C}P^n$:
$$ det \left (\frac{it\Omega}{2\pi} + Id \right) = \sum_{i}^n c_k(V)t^k $$
where $\Omega:=d\omega + \frac{1}{2}[\omega, \omega]$ with $\omega$ the connection form. I have two questions:
$$ $$
1) How can I calculate explicitly $\Omega$ for $T\mathbb{C}P^2$? What is the reason of this definition?
$$ $$
2) How can find explicitly the transition functions $g_{\alpha \beta}: U \rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{C})$?  ($U$ is a trivial open in $\mathbb{C}P^2$) How can I reduce $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ in $SU(2)$? And in what sense Chern classes represent the obstruction to reduce $U(n)$ in $SU(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to learn about moving frames. You naturally work with $\mathbb CP^n$ by lifting to a unitary frame on $\mathbb C^{n+1}$. (This is not unrelated to how Chern first developed Chern classes.) A bit more abstractly, you can think of $\mathbb CP^n$ as a symmetric space and get the connection and curvature form directly from the Lie algebraic structure. Unfortunately, this is not stuff that is clearly worked out in textbooks, to my knowledge.

Comment: But how can do explicitly the calculus of $\Omega$ in the case of $\mathbb{C}P^1$?

Comment: @ArthurStuart: I'm sure there are lots of options, but one I'm familiar with is my thesis from many years ago, "The Kinematic Formula in Complex Integral Geometry," Trans. Am. Math. Soc.,  264 (1981), pp. 255-293. I can send you a .pdf of it if you email me. There is also a discussion of the Euler sequence, which is what you need to get transition functions for $T(\mathbb CP^n)$.